# Get working directory the process was started with

Tags: python, windows, process, working-directory

Windows and Python.

Is it possible to get the working directory that a process (not under my control) was started with, after the current working directory is changed?

I suspect Windows will lose this info irremediably, but looking for a confirmation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As specified by [eryksun](https://stackoverflow.com/users/205580/eryksun):

> Python adds the script directory to sys.path, not the working
>   directory. The Windows ProcessParameters store the DosPath string and
>   Handle for the working directory. All traces of the initial working
>   directory are removed when a new working directory is set, i.e. the
>   DosPath string is updated and the old directory Handle is closed and
>   replaced by the new one. I checked whether auditing process creation
>   might help, but the audit event doesn't store the initial working
>   directory.